# Why would app crash if a method is put into viewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I placed a method in viewDidLoad() and it runs fine when the app runs.  It reads and writes data to and from the database. But, when I got into that particular view controller, it crashes!

Error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

But it is not nil as you can see from the image below

Why might it be crashing? Is it because I have it in view did load?

### Edit

This is the method that is placed in viewDidLoad:

```
let historyRef = ref.child("history")
    historyRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for history in snapshot.children {
                let snap = history as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                print("dict: \(dict)")
                let historyKey = snap.key
                print("History Key: \(historyKey)")

                    // fetch ride information ......

                let historyDB : FIRDatabaseReference = self.ref.child("history").child(historyKey)
                historyDB.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.exists() {
                        let rideId = snap.key // ... rideId
                        print("rideId: \(rideId)")

                        var distance = dict["distance"] as! Double // distance
                        distance = Double(round(1000 * distance)/1000)

                        let riderPaid = dict["riderPaid"] as! Bool // riderPaid
                        var ride_price = dict["ride_price"] as! Double // price before fees
                        var ryyde_fees = dict["ryyde_fees"] as! Double // ryyde_fees
                        var driver_payout = dict["driver_payout"] as! Double // driver_payout

                        if  riderPaid == true {
                            ride_price = Double(round(1000 * ride_price)/1000)
                            print("Ride Price: $ \(ride_price)")
                            ryyde_fees = Double(round(1000 * (ride_price * 0.25))/1000)
                            print("Ryyde Fees: $ \(ryyde_fees)")
                            driver_payout = Double(round(1000 * (ride_price - ryyde_fees))/1000)
                            print("Driver Payout: $ \(driver_payout)")

                            self.balance = self.balance + driver_payout
                            self.txtBalance.text = (String(format: "$ %.2f", self.balance))

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line that it crashes on is:

```
var distance = dict["distance"] as! Double // distance
distance = Double(round(1000 * distance)/1000)
```

if I comment this line out then it crashes on the next line ...

[image: results]

Comment: The error can't occur on two lines. Which of the two actually causes the error?

Comment: it crashes on the line 'var distance ..' if I comment that out and run the app again and go into this view controller, it crashes on the next line.

Comment: Clearly `dict` doesn't have the values you are trying to access and the forced cast (`as!`) is causing the crash. Use the debugger. Figure out why `dict` doesn't have the values you expect.

Comment: Please post what the value of distance is. Seems likely that it doesn't contain a "distance" key

Comment: I am going with @rmaddy on this. You've got a number of optional values with could be nil and they are not being handled very well. Those optionals should be safely unwrapped and if they are nil, give them a default value, abort the operation or employ some logic to handle it. See [nil coalescing](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID72) for one possible solution.

Comment: Please update your question with a snippet of your Firebase structure as that's probably related to the issue. Include it as TEXT please, no images. You can get it as text through the Firebase console->Export JSON. Oh - and the problem is probably because there is no *distance* child node so distance is nil and that affects the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I seen that the coded i had was added from another viewcontroller.
Question is not related anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes and this seems to work:

```
 let riderPaid: Bool = (dict["riderPaid"] != nil)// riderPaid
                        print("riderPaid: \(riderPaid)")
                        var ride_price: Double = dict["ride_price"] as? Double ?? 0.0  // price before fees
                        var ryyde_fees: Double = dict["ryyde_fees"] as? Double ?? 0.0 // ryyde_fees
                        var driver_payout: Double = dict["driver_payout"] as? Double ?? 0.0 // driver_payout
```

Comment: All that does is avoid the crash. It doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: I haven't been coding in Swift in over a year and I am not sure how to debug in Xcode anymore, there are so many options, I don't know what to pick. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @LizG Basic debugging in XCode has not changed in... well... ever. You still can add a breakpoint and step through your code line by line until you determine which line is crashing. Then you can examine the variables in the debugger prior to that line and see which one is not correct or nil. You should also read up on [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) and maybe look at a [Tutorial on Options](https://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/)